# Use search field value for JSON parameters

Tags: search, input, field

I'm trying to use the value of my search box 'address' as the 'tags' parameter from this code:

```
var args = {tags: document.getElementById('address').value, tagmode: "any", format:   "json"};

$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", args,
function flikr(data ) {
  $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
    $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#test");
    if ( i == 3 ) return false;
  });
});
```

however, flikr returns photos regardless of tags.

in the console,

```
args
```

returns:

```
Object {tags: "", tagmode: "any", format: "json"}
```

and,

```
args =  { tags: document.getElementById('address').value, tagmode: "any", format: "json"}
```

returns:

```
Object {tags: "london", tagmode: "any", format: "json"}
```

Comment: Soooo, whats the problem?

Comment: @BradM Wow, I just posted the same comment... (this is the edit).
I have no idea, I'm wondering too.

Comment: Hardly seems weird since there's no question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var search = document.getElementById('#address').value;
```

The "pound" sign is for selecting id's using jQuery. Remove it to win.

Comment: And we posted the (almost) same answer at (almost) the exact same time too. Great minds think alike!

Comment: thanks, that was one problem, but it still wont work. see edit

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "why is it not working", it's probably because you've got the JavaScript wrong. Line 3 should be

```
var search = document.getElementById('address').value;
```

If you really want to use the pound:

```
var search = document.querySelector('#address').value;
```

Comment: okay I've changed the code a little and amended your fix, however, flikr is now only returning the most recent photos, regardless of tags. The JS console shows this: Object {tags: "", tagmode: "any", format: "json"}.

Comment: @user2130426 It works fine for me... here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wqQyg/